# How to delete default resources in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I received an error msg while in compling for I deleted some default resources, like  'grossini_dance_atlas.png' or Default-568h@2x.png' from the resource folder. I guess it's a pretty basic problem but could any one tell me how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It means that file id deleted from your sources so you have to add both .png file in your source code.

Comment: Thank u. But could u tell me where to set those file id if i want to change'em?

Comment: When you create the project at that time that file @"Default-568h@2x.png" default in your resource bundel

Comment: what error message would that be?

Comment: likes i remove the file 'grossini_dance_atlas.png', and then it receives error msg like 'PBXCp Error:error: /Users/kaf/Desktop/LOCAL_GIT/test1/test1/Resources/grossini_dance_atlas.png: No such file or directory'. I guese I need to change something of 'Info.plist'. what do u say?

Comment: I guess it's the problem with project.pbxproj.